# Combine JSON with same value into JSON array - Scala

Tags: arrays, json, scala

I have converted a dataframe with columns email, account, id into json using `toJSON`. Each row is a JSON which looks like: `{"email": "xyz", "account": "pqr", "id": "1"}`.

The `id` field is not unique and I want to combine this array of JSON into array of JSON array such that each row is a array of JSONs with same `id` values.

For example: One row would look like: `[{"email": "xyz", "account": "pqr", "id": "1"},{"email": "abc", "account": "lmn", "id": "1"}]`

After this, I want to populate this JSON array into another dataframe `user` which has columns id and user.
The JSON array of each user with the matching `id` should be in the `user` dataframe.

O/p would be each row as: `| 1 | [{"email": "xyz", "account": "pqr", "id": "1"},{"email": "abc", "account": "lmn", "id": "1"}] |`

Can someone suggest how I can do this efficiently without exploding all the arrays multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure which JSON library you are using, so I'd recommend to convert to a case class which has an `id` field. You could then group by the `id` field and then insert into your `user` dataframe, converting the grouped rows to JSON.

Something along the lines of...

```
case class Row(email: String, account: String, id: String)

val rows: List[Row] = ??? // converted from your dataframe

rows.groupBy(_.id)
  .map { case (id, rows) =>
    // insert into user dataframe. Convert rows to JSON
  }
```